# SonarQube 5.6.1 and VSTS - No count for Unit Tests

Tags: unit-testing, sonarqube, azure-pipelines

We use VSTS with the newest SonarQube tasks and Sonarqube 5.6.1
In Sonarqube we see all the unit test coverage results, except for one item: The nr of unit tests. How/what do we need to configure to have the nr of unit tests also shown in Sonar Qube?

Answer (score 2):

Per [SonarC# documentation](https://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6389772), you need to import the Unit Test Execution Results, using the applicable property (for example *sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPath*). The trick is to set the appropriate value, which is not always straightforward in automated environments (e.g. VSTS).

Pending planned improvements with [SONARMSBRU-231](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARMSBRU-231), you may want to try the workaround mentioned in that ticket:

```
/d:sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths=..\**\TestResults\**\*.trx
```

(under *Advanced, Additional Settings* , in the *Prepare the SonarQube analysis* build step)